# What n represents in K= 2^2n mod m

Tags: algorithm, rsa, bit, montgomery-multiplication

I am doing a bit of studying of RSA algorithm implementation using montgomery modular multiplier and i am not sure what 2^2n stands for , is n number of bits of the message or is 2^2n number of bits of the message or is it something else.
page 6 in this pdf: http://www.journal.ftn.kg.ac.rs/Vol_11-1/11-Skobic-Dokic-Ivanovic.pdf

result C = P^e mod m
1. K= 2^2n mod m
2. Z= Monpro(1,K,M)
3. P= Monpro(P,K,m)
4. i=k-1 to i=0
   a. Z= Monpro(Z,Z,m)
   b. if ei = 1 then Z = Monpro(Z,P,m)
5. Z= Monpro(1,Z,m)
6. C=Z

Comment: bad article, 2^{2k} turn into 2^{2n}

Comment: thanks for fast answer !!!

Comment: better look at Koc's [articles](http://cetinkoc.net/docs/j47.pdf) and [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387338835)